# Dockerfile entrypoint failing in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

How does the Jenkins `Dockerfile` agent work?

I've defined my Dockerfile as

```
FROM hashicorp/terraform:latest
ENTRYPOINT ["terraform"]
```

And my Jenkinsfile as

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        dockerfile true
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh 'terraform version'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting an error in the console output asking me to check my `ENTRYPOINT`

ErrorMessage:

```
ERROR: The container started but didn't run the expected command. Please double check your ENTRYPOINT does execute the command passed as docker run argument, as required by official docker images (see https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency for entrypoint consistency requirements).
Alternatively you can force image entrypoint to be disabled by adding option `--entrypoint=''`.
```

I've looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency) but I can't seem to make sense of it.

What I expect to happen is that Jenkins will build the `hashicorp/terraform` image which I can then use as a build agent without having to install terraform on my server, but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Does anyone understand how this works?

Comment: The container already has the terraform code built.  no need for you to build it.

You need to include the actual error you saw to really get help here.  please edit your post to include that.

Comment: I believe latest is a synonym for the light tagged container (from reading about the container at docker hub).   The container as pulled already has /bin/terraform as the entrypoint:  see  https://hub.docker.com/layers/hashicorp/terraform/light/images/sha256-7e8d0325e120d8adae128bca9b3364c13a8c2f5109dffe681ac932a82b585729?context=explore

Comment: have you read:  https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/  it looks like you need to start with their image as mentioned in the link and the copy in the terraform data as done in the dockerfile in the link above.  But leave the entrypoint so that the docker agent code fires up right.   Then you should be able to use that agent and call out the terraform code in it (If I understood that all correctly).

Comment: I've removed the entry point but I'm still getting the same error. I've also tried changing the base image to `FROM hashicorp/terraform` but it's the same error either way.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to you.  I think the base image needs to be one that is mentioned in the plugins.jenkins.io link above.   Then you can grab the image id for the terraform image and try adding that as a layer.  I think the problem you may be running into is that jenkins is trying to run its agent and that is not present in the image you built with the current dockerfile.

Comment: FWIW @Hammed I have actually done something like this yet.  just going off what I know of jenkins, agents like this and the docs.   I might be on the track but I might not be....

Comment: Good point LhasaDad. Thanks for the pointer. Will have a look at this.